# sqlite3 connect python full path fails, works at command line

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a flask application that works file until I try and assign a full path to the location of my sqlite3 db. I will need to have a full path to allow the user to switch db's if need.

I have developed the app with the db's in the same location as the .py files now I have moved the db and it can't find the tables.

python code: I originally tried "+" before os.path.join.

```
BasePath = "/storage/resources/dbase/dbSTR/SS1/"
...
 tfile = os.path.join(BasePath,"dbSTR.db")
    print(tfile)
    conn = sqlite3.connect(tfile)
```

the tfile variable has : /storage/resources/dbase/dbSTR/SS1/dbSTR.db

The error is can't find strlocmotif table. i.e. db is empty.

Command line from where the .py file is stored:

```
sqlite3 /storage/resources/dbase/dbSTR/SS1/dbSTR.db
```

SQLite version 3.25.2 2018-09-25 19:08:10
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .tables
COHORTS         directives      hg19            newfeat2        strlocmotif
attribs         duplicates      meta            relations
autoincrements  features        newattrib       strloc

Answer (score 1):

It ended up working with the + syntax. I miss typed something. Thank You for your help!

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Good luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of the print statement? I think the last forward slash on the end of `BasePath` might be confusing `os.path.join()` if it doesn't expect it. You could try just manually concatenating the paths as strings and see if that works.

Comment: This is the output of the print:/storage/source/dbase/dbSTR/SS1/dbSTR.db   I will retry the + and drop the os.path.join()

Comment: BTW, I copied the output of the print and used it in the command line that worked. I wanted to check for typeos etc..

Comment: I just tested the code with + and still has the same error. Output of print is the same and I double checked and navigated to the location via the path entered and the db is located there.

Comment: What are the file permissions of the directory where the database is located? What are the permissions of the `dbSTR.db` file itself? The directory needs to be marked as executable for an application to work with files in the directory.

Comment: I had read that this could an issue so I set everything to 777 to be safe.